# Error calling hmrclient.setup (RNUpdate 0.63.2 -> 0.72.3)

Tags: android, react-native, updates, package.json, metro-bundler

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLKDj.png)
JSI rethrowing JS exception: Failed to call into JavaScript module method RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit(). Module has not been registered as callable. Bridgeless Mode: false. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 0): .
A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.

```
Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit(). Module has not been registered as callable. Bridgeless Mode: false. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 0):.    
A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
at invariant (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=apppname&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:3101:26)
```

I tried update RN and after got this error.